# Twitter profile section scrolls up to become the nav bar

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar

we are trying to create a profile section that would scroll up to become the nav bar like the way twitter does it. Any ideas of how to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you this post http://www.thinkandbuild.it/implementing-the-twitter-ios-app-ui/ it's perfectly explained step by step

Comment: thanks @agy the whole turtle is quite a good point for me to start at  :D

Answer (score 1):

Use a delegate method for UITableView:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Use `scrollView.contentOffset.y` to move your views around.
After it reaches top of navigation bar, you need to have another view there at the top (as a titleView for example) and animated it based on scroll offset.